# PayPal sandbox testing using postman

Tags: postman, paypal-sandbox

I have a website with PayPal payment method integrated in sandbox mode. How do I do negative testing using postman? I could not find it on the PayPal website. YouTube videos are all outdated or do not cover the topic. Where do I get the URL for the request and what are the steps to do everything further? Is there a method to do it without postman? All transaction seems to be successful or in "authorization" status even when there are not enough funds on a sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

By default sandbox accounts have a funding source (bank/cards) with unlimited funds when you create them.

Negative testing is documented in...[the negative testing guide.](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/sandbox/negative-testing/)